# jQuery: Check if all <DIV> or <Span> contains a specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I generate few boxes at runtime, where I want to confirm if all the boxes contains text "Empty", then the user should not be able to proceed. But if even a single Box contains the correct value of box (instead of Empty), then user should be able to proceed.

Please find me code below:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="bin-area empty floatLeft" style="width:242px; height:130px; ">
        <label for="9">
            <div class="bin" data-binid="0" data-cols="0" data-rows="0">
                <div class="number">S9</div>
                <input class="floatLeft styled" id="9" name="checkbox9" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="9"><span class="floatLeft marginLeft40">Empty</span>

                </label>
                <div class="type"></div>
                <div class="description">Storage</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="bin-area empty floatLeft" style="width:242px; height:130px; ">
        <label for="9">
            <div class="bin" data-binid="0" data-cols="0" data-rows="0">
                <div class="number">S9</div>
                <input class="floatLeft styled" id="9" name="checkbox9" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="9"><span class="floatLeft marginLeft40">Empty</span>

                </label>
                <div class="type"></div>
                <div class="description">Storage</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="bin-area" style=" width:242px; height:130px; ">
        <label for="8">
            <div class="bin" data-binid="5" data-cols="9" data-rows="5">
                <div class="number">S8</div>
                <input class="floatLeft styled" id="8" name="checkbox8" type="checkbox" />
                <div class="type">9x5 Storage Bin</div>
                <div class="description">Est. Capacity: 121 pkgs</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div role="button" style="margin-top:20px">
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomap" value="Automap" class="active" />
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomapBack" value="Back" class="active marginLeft50" />
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomapConfirm" value="Confirm &amp; Proceed" class="marginLeft10" />
</div>
```

This is my HTML structure... by searching some of the existing posts, I tried creating some IF logic using jQuery :

I tried this option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bin-area').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == 'Empty') {
            alert("Empty");
        }
    });
});
```

And this option:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("span.floatLeft").contains("Empty")) {
        alert("Empty");
    }
});
```

But nothing worked!

I have also created a fiddle to refer or try!

Please refer the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/xJtAV/**

Let me know if you need any other info.

Please suggest!

Comment: The problem really starts from you using jQuery syntax but haven't included the library itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do something if at least one box contains something other than "Empty", you don't need an each function.  Just do this:

```
if ($('.bin-area').length === $('.bin-area:contains("Empty")').length) {
    alert("Do nothing");
}
else {
    alert("Do something");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector like

```
 $('.bin-area:contains("Empty")')
```

Modified Code

```
$('.bin-area:contains("Empty")').each(function () {
    alert("Empty");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/xJtAV/9/)

Answer (score 3):

In your jsfiddle example use the `.find('span')` before `.text()`

```
if ($(this).find('span').text() === 'Empty') {
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
var els = $('.bin-area');
if (els.filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Empty') === -1;
}).length == els.length) {
    console.log('none of the divs contain "Empty".');
}
else {
    console.log('At least one of the divs contains "Empty".');
}
```

Caching the elements:

```
var els = $('.bin-area');
```

Comparing the number of elements that *do not* contain the word `'Empty'` in their text, against the number of the (previously-cached) elements:

```
els.filter(function(){
    return $(this).text().indexOf('Empty') === -1;
}).length == els.length) {
```

If they are the same lengths, then no `.bin-area` elements contain the word `'Empty'`, therefore do something to show that:

```
console.log('none of the divs contain "Empty".');
```

Otherwise, at least one of those elements *must* have contained the word `'Empty'` somewhere, therefore handle that:

```
else {
    console.log('At least one of the divs contains "Empty".');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.html()` attribute returns values from in between HTML tags, and I've used `find()` to go in and find the correct element you want to check in each iteration.

This works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bin-area').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('span.floatLeft').html() == 'Empty') {
            alert("Empty");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xJtAV/8/